# py2app Tkinter.pyc linking outside of app bundle

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I am trying to learn how to use py2app following the Sandwich.app tutorial ([1](https://www.metachris.com/2015/11/create-standalone-mac-os-x-applications-with-python-and-py2app/)).  I am using python2.7.11 installed from MacPorts along with py2app 0.9.1, also installed from MacPorts.

Running `python setup.py py2app` produces an app bundle that appears to work. However, if I "remove" my /opt/local directory (`sudo mv /opt/local /opt/local-save`), I find that the app depends on having files within my MacPorts install, specifically Tkinter.pyc tries to find tcl8.6 outside of the bundle:

> 6/5/16 9:08:02.561 AM Sandwich[79618]:   File "/Users/gbarnes/bin/sandwichApp/Sandwich.app/Contents/Resources/**boot**.py", line 351, in
>
> 6/5/16 9:08:02.561 AM Sandwich[79618]:     _run()
>
> 6/5/16 9:08:02.561 AM Sandwich[79618]:   File "/Users/gbarnes/bin/sandwichApp/Sandwich.app/Contents/Resources/**boot**.py", line 336, in _run
>
> 6/5/16 9:08:02.561 AM Sandwich[79618]:     exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
>
> 6/5/16 9:08:02.561 AM Sandwich[79618]:   File "/Users/gbarnes/bin/sandwichApp/Sandwich.app/Contents/Resources/Sandwich.py", line 8, in
>
> 6/5/16 9:08:02.561 AM Sandwich[79618]:     root = tk.Tk()
>
> 6/5/16 9:08:02.561 AM Sandwich[79618]:   File "Tkinter.pyc", line 1814, in **init**
>
> 6/5/16 9:08:02.561 AM Sandwich[79618]: _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
>
> 6/5/16 9:08:02.561 AM Sandwich[79618]:     /opt/local/lib/tcl8.6 /Users/gbarnes/bin/sandwichApp/Sandwich.app/Contents/lib/tcl8.6 /Users/gbarnes/bin/sandwichApp/Sandwich.app/lib/tcl8.6 /Users/gbarnes/bin/sandwichApp/Sandwich.app/Contents/library /Users/gbarnes/bin/sandwichApp/Sandwich.app/library /Users/gbarnes/bin/sandwichApp/Sandwich.app/tcl8.6.4/library /Users/gbarnes/bin/sandwichApp/tcl8.6.4/library
>
> 6/5/16 9:08:02.562 AM Sandwich[79618]: This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

Simply copying /opt/local/lib/tcl8.6 into one of the "following directories" results in additional problems (needing to copy tk8.6 into the same location followed by the app crashing with what appears to be fontconfig errors).

I feel that there must be something simple that I am missing and any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.